# Include table of contents in table of contents

Tags: libreoffice-writer

How do I make a "Table of Contents" entry in Libreoffice? I have the 'Title' style set to 'Heading 1', but it doesn't seem to want to reference itself inside the table.

For example, say I have a table of contents on page 2, with the title style set to Heading 1, this is a contents table I could get:

```
Blah Blah.....................1
Blah Blah more Blah...........3
```

The expected result would be:

```
Blah Blah.....................1
Table of Contents.............2
Blah Blah more Blah...........3
```

Does anyone know how to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by **adding the ToC heading separately**:

1. enter the heading
2. set paragraph style to Heading 1
3. hit enter to add a new paragraph, and
4. insert the ToC **with empty title**.

At first sight, two other approaches seem promising: setting the ToC heading paragraph style to "Heading 1" or another heading style, or by adding "Contents heading" paragraph style to the styles to create the toc from. Both won't work - LO ignores content inside the ToC field while creating the ToC itself.